# How can I submit form using ajax and get the response on a different page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my Form

```
<form id="new_type"  action="../control/c_type.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="type">Type<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" id="type" name="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Type..." required="required" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Description ..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group form-actions">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-danger" name="reset" value="reset">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Then I want to submit the form using ajax AND redirect the user to a different page and displays the response in a modal.

Here is my script

```
$('#new_type').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function(response) { // on success..
        $('#').html(response); // HERE I WANT TO REDIRECT THE USER TO ANOTHER PAGE AND DISPLAY THE RESPONSE IN A MODAL
    }
});
return false; // });
```

Kindly help me

Comment: if you're going to do that, then just use a regular postback with a redirect. This is defeating the point of ajax, which is to allow send/receive of data without postbacks and/or redirects.

Comment: You can save it in cookie maybe

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your answer, But how can I display a message to the user (using a modal) to say that the form submitted was successful or not?

Comment: By varying the output given by the server in each case. A simple `if` statement to change the HTML that is rendered back to the client. If it fails, render an error message. If it succeeds, render a success message, or initiate your desired redirect.

Comment: Yes @ADyson I have been able to display the message, just that it appears in a javascript alert window. But I want it in a modal.

Comment: well then, you have to insert some script into the page which triggers the modal to appear at page load (similar to what, I assume, you must have done to get the alert to display). Or render the modal HTML in-place, so it will be part of the displayed HTML already. It depends entirely how you are creating modals. Or think of some less obtrusive UX - e.g. if the form is invalid a lot of sites display a small message above it, or highlight the fields that are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do trick in action url, store all variable in session, redirect user to another page, then get all data and display to user. only this is the way, ajax can't transfer all data to another page, u must use some backend technique to store variable in session, if you don't want use server side technology you can also store the data in local browser store and get the variable in another page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @XainBinKafeel for your answer  but what I actually want is to be able to display a message to the user after form submission. I'm able to generate that message just that it appears in a javascript alert window. But I want it in a modal.